# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForOfficialRelease'. > Cannot invoke method getMainManifest() on null object

Tags: android-studio, gradle

This occurs when I run it on Release channel of Android Studio.

part of my gradle here:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inst.instcallcar"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.00"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    productFlavors {
        official {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sign
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sign
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it using gradle version 1.14.1, 3.1 and 3.2, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is result from this issue: [ThinRPlugin#2](https://github.com/mogujie/ThinRPlugin/issues/2)

I delete `ThinRPlugin` for that issue has not resolved.

It's ok now.